# Display PDF as actionResult after getting file from rest service in C#

Tags: c#, rest, pdf

First of all I am french so pardon my english. 
I have a rest service which generate and send a PDF file, I would like to get and display the PDF from an action result on the client side. I am fairly new in C# and tried solutions around google, and Stack Overflow, of course, and can't seem to make it work... Also most answers I find save the PDF on the computer but I couldn't find answers about opening it inside the browser or how to combinate it with an `ActioResult`

The REST service code :

```
[Route("api/getPdf/{login}/{password}/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage getPDF(string login, string password, int id)
{
    try
    {
        if (this.Authenticate(login, password) != null)
        {
            forms forms = db.forms.Find(id);
            if (forms == null)
            {
                var messageNotFound = string.Format("Form with id = {0} not found", id);
                HttpError errAut = new HttpError(messageNotFound);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, errAut);
            }

            var html = XmlHelper.GetHtml(forms.data, forms.annexe.ToString());

            // instantiate the html to pdf converter
            HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();

            // convert the url to pdf
            PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(html);

            // save pdf document
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            doc.Save(ms);

            // close pdf document
            doc.Close();

            var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray());
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".pdf";
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

            return response;

        }
        var messageAutheticationFailed = string.Format("Authentication failed", id);
        HttpError err = new HttpError(messageAutheticationFailed);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.ProxyAuthenticationRequired, err);
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        throw exp;
    }
}
```

The website side code I tried :

```
public ActionResult pdf(int id)
{

    string html = string.Empty;
    string url = URL + login + "/" + PASSWORD + "/" + id;

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        html = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //string resBody
    }
    return File(html, "application/pdf");
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Edit: The browser correctly render the PDF if I directly put the URL of the API.

I managed to find a solution :

```
public ActionResult pdf(int id)
    {

        string html = string.Empty;
string url = URL + login + "/" + PASSWORD + "/" + id;


        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                byte[] content = memoryStream.ToArray();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=test.pdf");
                return File(content, "application/pdf");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should understand where the problem actually is, on server or client side.

So that client could correctly recognize response as PDF file, server should set `Content-Type` header to `application/pdf` in the response. You correctly used `File(html, "application/pdf")` method for this purpose. But the piece that confuses me is that override of `File` method with string parameter takes a file name not the content itself: `File(string fileName, string contentType)`. But from your snippet it looks like `html` variable contains downloaded content from external REST service. With such implementation server should throw `FileNotFoundException`. So at first check whether server correctly completes request (status code 200) and sends `Content-Type` header equal to `application/pdf`.

Then, when client (a browser) receives the response, it's completely his responsibility to select a behavior for such content. It could propose to save it on disk or render PDF with internal capabilities or using plugin or extension. It varies from browser to browser and could be configured for major browsers. So you could try opening PDF document from some known resource (e.g. [this one](http://www.club-mba.com/wp-content/uploads/Practice_Test_A.pdf)) and check how your browser will behave. It will save you from searching for issues with your code when your browser just do not render PDFs.

Comment: I should have mention it, but my browser indeed correctly open PDF when I directly put the API's URL or your link. So I don't think the problem comes from my browser or from the server. The issue must come from something I do wrong on the client, I think.

Comment: By "API's URL" you mean url to REST call ("api/getPdf/")? Then the problem should be with `File()` call as I described above.

Comment: I found a solution indeed I was incorrectly using `File` searched google a bit on how to use and voilà, it works. Thanks.